# Laravel check if cookie exits

Tags: cookies, laravel-5

I am newer in Laravel. I'd like to make web page gets redirected to another domain if cookie does't exists. for ex: when i enter to www.somesite.com, let it checks first cookie ($_COOKIE['SSO-Token']). if there is not one it redirects to another domain for logging. I need to make it only in Laravel. Any helps greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance to anyone who will help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cookie has been set, you can show with:

```
public function showCookie(Request $request) {
        return $request->cookie('name');
    }
```

To check for specific cookie:

```
$value = $request->cookie('name');
if($value)
{
   //cookie exists
}
```

See [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#cookies)